# Business Process Flows stage without a step

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

The Business Process Flows mainly consists of Stages, Steps and Workflows.
When defining a Step you can link it to an existing Field in the entity.

The question I would like to ask is: can you define a Step which is NOT linked to an entity field? 
I am using an on-premise CRM installation and, unless I am missing an obvious way, the built in editor does does not allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately No, there should be a minimum one Data step (Field) atleast in a stage.

It's meant to use for stage-gating using field (data step) for advancing the flow stage. Maybe you can add some non-mandatory field & hide it using javascript.